# Expressão Regular | Pegar parte de conteúdo entre 2 marcadores

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Não possuo conhecimento nenhum de expressão regular, então não sei se e possível fazer realizar a solução do meu problema.

> Em todo o código HTML de um site, ele sempre possui um código semelhante a este.

```
"placeholder":"https:\/\/ci.hdv6.com\/videos\/78\/13\/8787575\/thumbs_65\/(m=eaAaGwObaaaweyaY)(mh=c_sPzVwXUfENWpYI)6.jpg",
```

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte.

Pegar todo o conteudo que começa em:

> "placeholder":"

E termina em:

> ",

No caso seria:

```
https:\/\/ci.hdv6.com\/videos\/78\/13\/8787575\/thumbs_65\/(m=eaAaGwObaaaweyaY)(mh=c_sPzVwXUfENWpYI)6.jpg
```

> OBS: Estou usando o CURL para pegar todo o HTML de um site, assim posso achar um techo igual a este para pegar apenas este link.

E extremamente importante pegar através da palavra PLACEHOLDER como marcador inicial, pois existem outros links similares no site.

Comment: Gostaria se possível, nas linguagens PHP ou Javascript

Comment: em php seria `(?<="placeholder":").*(?=")`

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "placeholder:https:\/\/ci.hdv6.com\/videos\/78\/13\/8787575\/thumbs_65\/(m=eaAaGwObaaaweyaY)(mh=c_sPzVwXUfENWpYI)6.jpg"

let result = /https.+jpg$/.exec(string)[0]

console.log(result);
```